# Matlab integral with parameter

Tags: matlab

I'm a beginner with Matlab, and I'm trying to solve the following problem.

I'd like to define a function 
$$F(x) = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin t}{1 + xt^4} \, dt$$
and plot it on the interval $[1,3]$.

I wrote the following code:

```
x = 1:0.01:3; 
y = []; 

for i = 1:201
    xi = 1 + (i-1)/100;
    y(i) = quadgk(@(t)sin(t)./(xi*t.^4 + 1), 0, inf); 
end 

plot(x,y)
```

This looks ridiculously complicated to me, and there's no obvious way to compute values of $F(x)$ after this.

I'd like to know how experienced Matlab users would program this.

Comment: Matlab's main purpose is not to do symbolic calculations.  It can be done, as you've shown.  But usually (at least in my experience) Matlab is used for numerics rather than symbolics.

Comment: In this case, I'm mainly interested in numerical calculations. I'd like to simplify the syntax, even if internally Matlab is doing the equivalent of a for loop.

Comment: You do not need to integrate up to $\infty$ (I guess you only want a plot and not an superaccurate answer) Since the function falls off like $1/(1+xt^4)$ it should be enough to go up to say $xt^4 \approx 10^2 - 10^3$, i.e. try to integrate from $t=0$ to $t=10$. It should speed up the computation.

Comment: Doesn't Matlab do that automatically? I mean, can't it bound the integrand so that *it* decides where to cut off the integral?

Comment: Matlab's quadgk does allow integration over infinite intervals (as long as the integrand decays rapidly enough).  Its methods are rather more sophisticated, I think, than picking a finite cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

I might do it this way:

```
integrand = @(x) (@(t) sin(t) ./ (1+x .*t .^4));

F = @(x) quadgk(integrand(x),0,Inf);

x = 1:0.01:3;
y = arrayfun(F,x);

plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get "Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead." and some other stuff. I'm using a 2012 version of Matlab. Could that be why? Or is it something to do with declaring the types of the variables?

Comment: Did you have to enter any commands like "syms x", etc., before executing this?

Comment: Oops, left out some "."'s.  Fixed now.

Comment: It works now. If I understand correctly, integrand is a function which, evaluated at x, gives you a function of t. So integrand(x) is actually a function of t. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: How would I evaluate the integrand for x = 2 and t = 6, for example? I tried integrand(2)(6) and that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the example. That really helps.

Comment: I think it needs two steps:
q = integrand(2);
q(6)